# I have a problem with a ggplot 2 barchart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a histogram with this data.
I am using `geom_bar` cause I have struggled with `geom_histogram()`

```
library(ggplot2)

roki=c(2015,2016,2017,2018,2019) 
wart=c(9.7,8.2,6.6,5.8,5)        
bezrob=data.frame(roki,wart)     

ggplot(bezrob, aes(x=roki, y=wart))  

ggplot(bezrob, aes(x=roki,y=wart))+geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

This is what I get:

[image: bar plot]

My question is: How can I delete the gaps between bars? I really want to create a histogram, not a bar plot but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Just set `geom_bar` argument `width = 1.0`, the default is 0.9

Comment: Do you know what a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) is?

Answer (score 1):

`geom_histogram` takes only the x dimension to compute count and density. You don't have that much data so there will be gaps. If it is too much a problem the help (see `?geom_histogram`) should inform you on how to use the `binwidth` argument.

```
ggplot(bezrob, aes(x = wart)) + geom_histogram()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try “width” inside aes and "colour" inside geom_bar:

```
ggplot(bezrob, aes(x=roki,y=wart, width = 1)) + 
geom_bar(stat='identity', colour = 'red')
```

Inside geom_bar you can control the color of the bars with "fill" for example fill = 'blue' and the lines with "colour" or "color".

Regards,